# Search price Grid

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a way to find values within a table: Lets say I have width of 551 and a drop of 551 then the search values should round upward to 600 width x 600 drop and the answer should be 66.6.

Could someone help me put together a formula to calculate these references.

```
        Drop                        
Width           400     450     500     550     600     650
        500    47.6    51.8    56.0    60.2    64.4    68.6
        550    48.4    52.7    57.0    61.2    65.5    69.8
        600    49.2    53.5    57.9    62.3    66.6    71.0
        650    50.0    54.4    58.8    63.3    67.7    72.2
        700    50.7    55.3    59.8    64.3    68.8    73.4
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the data values fun in the range of C3:H7, you can use `INDEX` and `MATCH`, along with `MROUND` to round your input to match the required values:

```
=INDEX(C3:H7, MATCH(MROUND(575,50),B3:B7,0), MATCH(MROUND(575,50),C2:H2,0))
```

Replace `575` with the reference to the cell where you are putting the value.

If you have a table to fill, it'll be easier if you lock some addresses and drag the formula:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$H$7, MATCH(MROUND(575,50),$B$3:$B$7,0), MATCH(MROUND(575,50),$C$2:$H$2,0))
```

---

EDIT: As per your update, all values should be rounded up. In this case, use `CEILING`:

```
=INDEX(C3:H7, MATCH(CEILING(551,50),B3:B7,0), MATCH(CEILING(551,50),C2:H2,0))
```

[And add the locks if required]

Comment: Hi Jerry, Just applied this formula and tested it on a number of variables and it appears to be giving me an incorrect response. After a little research I see the Mround function rounds up or down to the closest value, in this case "50". I need the value to round up to either "50's" or "100's"

Have I misunderstood this? 

In any case the formula is giving the wrong response.

Comment: another example of my pricing books have widths and drops that increase by 200. How can I apply 200 units variation to a formula?

Comment: Got it. 'MROUND' was not required instead I took your formula did a bit of research and finally came up with the following. 

       '=INDEX($C$3:$H$7, MATCH(575+50,$B$3:$B$7,1), MATCH(575+50,$C$2:$H$2,1))'

Comment: @TonyCruise Your question was not representative of your true data then. Please update your question accordingly. Note that for the given information you provided, that formula works fine.

Comment: my question asked to round values up while your answer rounds values close to 50 down. Say I have a value of 551. The value should round to 600 not 550 which is what it does in your formula. The question clearly asks to round up.

Comment: @TonyCruise That wasn't clear because most of the time, people round things up when it's more than a certain threshold and down when it's below that threshold.  E.g. if you go buy something at the market and the total is $60.01 (or whatever currency you use), I can't imagine people paying that extra 1 cent. But now that you clarified things up, then the appropriate formula would be `CEILING`.

Answer (score -1):

```
=INDEX($C$3:$H$7, MATCH(551+50,$B$3:$B$7,1), MATCH(551+50,$C$2:$H$2,1))
```

The Above modified code will source the value pertaining to '551' Wide with a '551' Drop. Substitute the '551' with any value and a value will be obtained. In this case the drop and width is rounded up.

The process of the MATCH function rounds down. In this case when pricing a value of 575 width it needs to be rounded up. The only way to achieve this is to add 50 and then allow the function to round the value down

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? You answered your own question, but we want answers to be useful to the community, so we'd like to see an explanation.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're posting an answer, or a comment reply? If you're posting a comment, use the "add comment" button below your question. Don't use the answer area for comments.

Comment: The Above modified code will source the value pertaining to '575' Wide with a '575' Drop. Substitute the '575' with any value and a value will be obtained. In this case the drop and width is rounded up. @dragonLord

Comment: You should still edit that into the answer. Comments are meant for suggestions and questions regarding the post itself. The code by itself doesn't make a good answer.

Comment: I don't see how this formula addresses the part in your question mentioning "the search values should round upward to 600 width x 600 drop" because here, 575 is being increased to 625, and not 600.

Comment: The process of the MATCH function rounds down. In this case when pricing a value of 575 width it needs to be rounded up. The only way to achieve this is to add 50 and then allow the function to round the value down.